# symfony2 no route params while injecting request into service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.4

I ran into a problem while developing with symfony 2.4.

I'm trying to inject request into my service which is a user provider. Everything works fine except there are no route params.

So this is my bundle's routing.yml:

```
skedl_web_homepage_backend:
    pattern: /
    host: '{account}.{domain}'
    defaults: { _controller: SkedlWebBundle:Backend:index }
    requirements:
        domain: '%domain%'
```

My login and registration forms are not far from the onces from the documentation.

Here's my bundle's services.yml:

```
parameters:
    user_provider.class: Skedl\WebBundle\Service\UserProvider

services:
    user_provider:
        class: "%user_provider.class%"
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @request_stack ]
```

security.yml:

```
providers:
    main:
        id: user_provider
```

And finally a piece from my UserProvider.php:

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        var_dump($requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
        die;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get 'account' param from request attributes, but it's totally empty:

```
  ["attributes"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["request"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#7 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["query"]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#8 (1) {
    ["parameters":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

I set up a request listener and I can get the 'account' param there with no problems.
I tried to use scopes but there was no luck (ScopeWideningInjectionException).
Am I missing something here?

Thank you.

Comment: Figured out the problem. It was dev environment (_wdt) that broke my request content :-(
What would be the practice to avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: please post your solution as an answer. so this question becomes complete.

Comment: @ns3777k probably you are looking for this in the security.yml file:
`firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false`

Comment: [here](http://codeshare.io/HFCrQ) you will find the well formatted version...